# JDBI PostgreSQL: Get result of function from PSQL Call

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, jdbi

I have a simple PSQL script

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(bar text) RETURNS text AS $$
    BEGIN
        --some stuff
        RETURN bar;
    END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And I want to extract the returned statement of

```
SELECT foo('hi') as result;
```

into my JDBI program in Java.

So currently I have this,

```
public String test() {
        Handle h = dbi.open();
        try {
            OutParameters ret = h.createCall("SELECT foo('hi') as result;").invoke();
            return ret.getString("result");
        } finally {
            h.close();
        }
    }
```

But I keep getting met with

```
Exception 'Parameter result does not exist'
```

What's the proper way of getting the results of PSQL function calls from JDBI?

Comment: No need for `createCall()` just run that as a regular `select` statement using the equivalent of `executeQuery()`

Comment: Can I get the output parameters from `executeQuery()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jdbi.org/#_stored_procedure_calls

It looks like JDBC has it's own format for outparameters in the form of

```
OutParameters result = handle
        .createCall("{:sum = call add(:a, :b)}") 
        .bind("a", 13) 
        .bind("b", 9) 
        .registerOutParameter("sum", Types.INTEGER)   
        .invoke();
```